# Add an Object to array in React.js

Tags: reactjs

It is a simple question I know but right now I am struggling with it. Simply I am trying to add a new Object to an array which getting from the input. Here is simple form inside render:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitTopic}>
        <input onChange={this.handleTopicName} placeholder="add topic name" /><br />
        <input onChange={this.handleQ1} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <input onChange={this.handleQ2} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <button>Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

here is onChange handle functions:

```js
handleTopicName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ topicName: e.target.value });
  }

  handleQ1 = (e) => {
    const question = e.target.value;
    const qInput = {
      answer: 'no answer',
      question,
      questionId: uuid(),
    };
    const qArray = this.state.questions.slice();
    qArray.push(qInput);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ questions: qArray }));
  }

  handleQ2 = (e) => {
    const qInput = {
      answer: 'no answer',
      question: e.target.value,
      questionId: uuid(),
    };
    const qArray = this.state.questions.slice();
    qArray.push(qInput);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ questions: qArray }));
  }

  handleSubmitTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSaveTopic({
      topicName: this.state.topicName,
      questions: this.state.questions,
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

and last here is state:

```js
state = {
  topicName: '',
  questions: [],
}
```

I have tried adding Objects with spread operator like that

```
this.setState({questions: [...this.state.questions, {here goes question object}]})
```

Every time after submitting the results I get an array of every character I typed.

here is a screenshot of results:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are adding an object to the array on input change. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I just want to add a new object when I save form

Comment: @anarzone just use onBlur event on input instead of onChange. <input onBlur={this.handleTopicName} placeholder="add topic name" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different answer, but this changes your code logic drastically.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topicName: '',
    inputs: {},
    questions: [],
  }

  handleTopicName = e =>
    this.setState({ topicName: e.target.value });


  handleInputs = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState(prevState => ({ inputs: { ...prevState.inputs, [name]: value } }));
  }

  handleSubmitTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {inputs} = this.state;
    const questions = Object.keys(inputs).map( key => (
      {
        answer: 'no answer',
        question: inputs[key],
      //questionId: uuid(),
      }
    ));
    
    this.setState({ questions });

    /* this.setState( { questions }, () => 
      this.props.onSaveTopic( {
        topicName: this.state.topicName,
        questions,
      } )
     );*/
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitTopic}>
        <input onChange={this.handleTopicName} placeholder="add topic name" /><br />
        <input name="q1" onChange={this.handleInputs} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <input name="q2" onChange={this.handleInputs} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <button>Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I've create one function to handle inputs: `handleInputs`. This function handles both inputs with their `name` attribute. So, we are using those inputs for creating `questions`. This is done in `handleSubmitTopic` function.

Here, using `inputs` object we are mapping it into a new `questions` array. In the working code I just set `questions` state. Thanks to that snippet works. If you comment that out and use you version, you can use `onSaveTopic`. Here, after setting `questions` state, in the `setState` callback function we are doing this since `setState` is asynchronous.

Also, there is a `console.log` in `render` method to see what is going on here.

Comment: Your code does not work as intended because you are setting state immediately after each key stroke. This is why you see separate characters. So, to solve this issue I hold the values in a different state then create the questions using it. Maybe there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Use onBlur Event instead of onChange.
OnBlur is trigger when focus out of the input element. 
onChange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitTopic}>
        <input onBlur={this.handleTopicName} placeholder="add topic name" /><br />
        <input onBlur={this.handleQ1} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <input onBlur={this.handleQ2} type="text" placeholder="add question" /><br />
        <button>Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It does not completely solve the problem, it is almost same while I'm typing when I click outside of the input and then delete what I've typed again the same problem occurs, I get an array of what I typed before and after deleted

Comment: this answer won't solve the issue